# Why this C program (erroneously) outputs the powers of 2 for large numbers?

Tags: c

I have a simple C program to find the factors of a given number.

It compiles and runs fine up to numbers 1e10 or 1e11.

But for numbers that are larger than that, the output (erroneously) consists mostly to be the powers of 2.

2, 4, 16, 32 ... 329033728, 658067456, 1316134912

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
    int inp;
    int size = 0;
    int *p = &size;
    puts("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &inp);
    int *arr = (int*) calloc(inp/4, sizeof(int));
    for(int i =2;i<=inp; i++){
        if (inp%i == 0){
     
        *(arr+size) = i;
        *p += 1;
        }
    }
       int j = 0;
        while(arr[j] != 0){
         printf("%d\n", arr[j]);
         j++;
        }
         free(arr);
       return 0;
}
```

What is the reason for this strange behavior?

Have I exhausted all memory on my machine?

Any explanation would be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Please enable warnings, your compiler should be emitting some warnings for your `scanf` call. Hint: What type of argument does the `scanf` format `%d` expect? What is the type of `&inp`?

Comment: Maybe an int64_t instead of an int would help. 1e10 exceeds 2^31.

Comment: When I see "large numbers, problem" I think "ignored representable range or has an overflow".

Comment: I changed int to off64_t. Now, gdb shows segmentation fault from 1e10 `Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x004016cf in main () at _c:13 13 *(arr+size) = i; `(It compiles and runs up to 1e9). I changed it back to int and it compiles and runs 1e10.

Comment: What do you mean by "1e10"? Do you enter `"1e10"` on the input prompt or `10000000000`?

Comment: 1e10 numbers. I inputted `1000000000`

Comment: Sorry, 1e10 can be only one number. I inputted `10000000000`

Comment: `int` is commonly a 32-bit signed integer type. It can hold values in the range from around - two billion to plus two billion. Any decent beginners class, tutorial or book should have this information.

Comment: Thanks. Sure, I should have done 'bounds checking'. I had this buffer overflow, indeed. I included the stdint.h header file and changed the type to int64_t. Now my problem is real. With the above piece of code, I actually run out of memory for very large numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `printf("%d\n", inp)` after `scanf("%d", &inp)`. Is that the same number you entered, or is it different? If it's different, congratulations: you've become well-acquainted with the notorious Mr. Overflow.